# Need to set a filepath to db from input form

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in separate db and I am using Fabrik 3.8 with them.
In the first one I have an input field from which users can set the record id of the second table where is also stored a file name.
I need to set a php function in the module plugin that on form submission will store the id in the first table (column id) and then look at the second table with that id and retrieve the corresponding filename and in the end set in the first table (column filepath) a filepath with a concat function from that filename.
I guess that I will need something like this:

```
<?php
mysql_query("
      UPDATE db1.caduti 
        SET db1.caduti.filepath = CONCAT("/images/joomgallery/originals/foto/", db2.jos_joomgallery.imgfilename);
            WHERE db2.jos_joomgallery.id = db1.caduti.id_joomgallery
            ")
?>
```

But I'm thinking that it will update all the records that match the id from two tables. I need to update only the record that I am editing. Any help?

Comment: You need to figure out a way to specify your WHERE with a single result.  If the information you can filter on links to multiple rows, ask for more details from the user, or force the entry to be unique at the database level (i.e. remove duplicates!)

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be like this:

```
mysql_query("
      UPDATE db1.caduti 
        SET db1.caduti.filepath = CONCAT('/images/joomgallery/originals/foto/', db2.jos_joomgallery.imgfilename)
            WHERE db2.jos_joomgallery.id = db1.caduti.id_joomgallery");
```